# Ant design 3 Year picker selected value not display

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

Im using  react type script project for **[ant design3 date picker](https://3x.ant.design/components/date-picker/)**, they are not provided year picker and i got a some solution and is it here   `mode="year"`, then year picker is working but cant bind the value , selected year not display. any one know some solution for this?

**[stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zfhaoi?file=index.js)**

Thanks

**code here**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';

const { MonthPicker, RangePicker, WeekPicker, } = DatePicker;

function onChange(date, dateString) {
  console.log(date, dateString);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DatePicker onChange={onChange} mode="year" placeholder="Select year"/>
    <br />
        <br />
   

  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one of [FAQ](https://3x.ant.design/docs/react/faq#When-set-mode-to-DatePicker/RangePicker,-cannot-select-year-or-month-anymore?) on antd version 3

**When I set mode to DatePicker/RangePicker, I cannot select year or month anymore?**

> In a real world development, you may need a YearPicker,
> MonthRangePicker or WeekRangePicker. You are trying to add mode to
> DatePicker/RangePicker expected to implement those pickers. However,
> the DatePicker/RangePicker cannot be selected and the panels won't
> close now.
>
> Like the explaination here, that is because 
> do not equal to YearPicker,  do not equal
> to MonthRangePicker either. The mode property was added to support
> showing time picker panel in DatePicker in antd 3.0, which simply
> control the displayed panel and won't change the original date picking
> behavior of DatePicker/RangePicker (for instance you still need to
> click date cell to finish selection in a DatePicker, whatever the mode
> is).

And here is one of the workaround

> You can refer to this [article](https://juejin.im/post/6844903859987415047) or this article, using mode and
> onPanelChange to encapsulate a YearPicker or MonthRangePicker for your
> needs. Or you can wait for our [antd@4.0](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/), in which we are planing to
> add more XxxPickers for those requirments.

Seems that you can use the `onPanelChange` to get the value

```
<Datepicker mode="year" onPanelChange={(value) => console.log(value)} />
```

check working code here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zfhaoi-hzwlgx?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a different version of antd?
This demo is working correctly. [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2qcnp).

```
  <DatePicker onChange={onChange} picker="year" />
```

Comment: yes, I cant update to my project in the ant design version 4, im already using ant design 3, when i updated the 3 to 4 i  faced lot of conflict